# SSD NVME M2 is not detected during ubuntu 20.04 installation Lenovo

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, lenovo

I buyed a Lenovo v15 which comes with an SSD NVME. I've installed windows 10 but I also want to make a dual boot with ubuntu 20.04. The problem I'm having is that when I start the installation it only recognizes the memory from boot USB and it doesn't recognize the hard disk memory. I saw other posts, but that are for other brands and the BIOS is different.

Comment: It doesn't matter if the firmware - UEFI, not BIOS - is different, the problem is likely the same in all this cases: Incompatible drive modes. "RAID" or Intel RST isn't (yet) supported, it must be set to AHCI and, of course, you should have done it before installing Windows. Now you need to install AHCI support before changing and finally being able to install the dual-boot.

Comment: Did you install Windows in UEFI boot mode to gpt partitioned drive? Have you updated UEFI & NVMe firmware? Some Lenovo have this: The Device Guard BIOS setting locks down the boot order to internal HDD/SSD only. Lenovo V15 G2 ALC Ryzen 5700U + Ubuntu 21.04
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2462880&page=2

Answer (score -1):

Solved installing ubuntu 22.04.